# how to add custom format to QMovie in python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a simple widget that uses QMovie to display animated gif on a QLabel. This works really well. I would like to implement my own format and add it to supported formats in QMovie (all in python). Is it possible?

QMovies `supportedFormats()` returns two supported formats:

`[PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray(b'gif'), PySide2.QtCore.QByteArray(b'webp')]`

What is the way to extend it?

I can simply subclass QLabel and make it work with my custom format but if feels like extending QMovie supported formats is the "correct" way of handling the problem. I cannot find any examples or even docs about it online.

Comment: You can't. QMovie uses QImageReader, which uses QImageIOHandler instances created through QImageIOPlugin subclasses. Since that class is not exposed to the python bindings, that makes it not possible.

Comment: thank you @musicamante. that explains why I wasn't able to find any information and failed to implement it in my various attempts.

Comment: Note that, while we would be more than happy to have Python binding support for QImage plugin extensions, it wouldn't probably be that helpful. Image loading is supposed to be as fast as possible (something python doesn't do very well, at least directly), meaning that you'd need to create a very complex and extremely fast implementation for that (possibly using external libraries). That's most certainly not worth it, and if you're capable of that, you're probably able to do it in C++. Just implement your custom painting: it may not be as performant as you'd wish, but it's *way* easier.

Comment: my actual user case is very simple. I have a "filmstrip" which is a long jpg file with frames in a row (do not ask, autodesk shotgrid requirement). It is trivial in python to load it in one go to memory and chop one frame at time from it. No need for c++ as I'm using built in fast jpg loader. Anyway I have it working as a custom QLabel I simply wanted it to be "pure" and add as a custom format to QMovie.

Comment: Yes you need to implement a ```QImageIOPlugin``` and ```QImageIOHandler``` as musicamante said. What about [```cppyy```](https://cppyy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)? You can easily subclass a native C++ class at the Python side.